# i am having an error on my txtfile reader prgram

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class GradeAverage {

    private String filename;
    private List<String> invalidEntries;
    private List<Entry> validEntries;

    public GradeAverage() {
        invalidEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        validEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private static class Entry{
        private String name;
        private List<Integer> grades;
        public Entry() {
        grades = new ArrayList<>();

        public void add(int g){
            grades.add(g);
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public double getAverage(){

            if(grades.size() == 0)
                return 0.0;

            double avg = 0.0;
            for(Integer x: grades){
                avg += x;
            }
            avg /= grades.size();
            return avg;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return name + " " + getAverage() + "\n";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GradeAverage gradeApp = new GradeAverage();
        System.out.println("gradesheet.txt");
        gradeApp.setFilename("gradesheet.txt");

        gradeApp.readFile();
        gradeApp.process();

    }

    private void process() {
        Entry max = new Entry();
        Entry min = new Entry();
        for(Entry entry : validEntries){
            if(max.getAverage() < entry.getAverage())
            {
                max = entry;
            }
            if(min.getAverage() >= entry.getAverage())
            {

                System.out.println("READ");
                min = entry;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("MAX:\t"+max);
        System.out.print("MIN:\t"+min);
        System.out.println("\nExcluded Entries:");
        for(String str: invalidEntries){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    private void readFile() {
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.exit(404);
        }
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String nextLine = in.nextLine();
            try{
                Entry entry = new Entry();
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(nextLine);
                String name = tokenizer.nextToken();
                if(!valid(name))
                    throw new Exception();
                entry.setName(name);
                while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                    entry.add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                }
                validEntries.add(entry);
    //              System.out.print("added\n"+entry);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                invalidEntries.add(nextLine);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }

    private boolean valid(String name) {
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i){
            if(!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

}
```

this code is for getting minimum and maximum average of the grade. However when it is trying to show a minimum grade, result is keep showing null 0.0. here is the example.

**Input**

> I 30 12 43
>
> 64 46 love
>
> code 22 2 2 113
>
> somuch 13 99

**Output**

> gradesheet.txt
>
> MAX:  somuch 56.0
>
> MIN:  null 0.0
>
> Excluded Entries: 64 46 love

what did i do wrong? i really need help...

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to answer if you could provide an [mcve].

Comment: Should the average be 28.33333 ? If we supply the above input?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, with this:

```
Entry max = new Entry(); // defaultly constructed, so max.getAverage() == 0
Entry min = new Entry(); // defaultly constructed, so min.getAverage() == 0
for(Entry entry : validEntries){ // entry has only positive grades
    ....
    if(min.getAverage() >= entry.getAverage()) // 0 >= 'something, greater than 0' is always false.
}
```

It is considered wise, when using simillar algorithm for finding minimun/maximum values, to initialize default values (`Entry max` and `Entry min` in your case) with first element of the list. So change previous into

```
Entry max = validEntries[0];
Entry min = validEntries[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the following portion of code causes min to stay 0.0 as long as there is no negative value. See comments below:

```
        Entry max = new Entry();
        Entry min = new Entry();
        //min.getAverage() is 0.0 for the first ever time
        //max.getAverage() is 0.0 for the first ever time
        for(Entry entry : validEntries){
            if(max.getAverage() < entry.getAverage())
            {
                //0.0 is < entry.getAverage(), so max works file
                max = entry;
            }
            if(min.getAverage() >= entry.getAverage())
            {
                /* is 0.0 >= entry.getAverage(), no unless entry.getAverage is less than 0.0 hence, this condition is not executed until the entry.getAverage() is not a negative value */
                System.out.println("READ");
                min = entry;
            }
        }
```

I decided that when the for loops through the first entry, I will set both min and max with average of entry lets say x (using boolean flag) and in subsequent loops I compare the previously stored values in min and max and I am guaranteed to always get correct values. If there is only one input then both min and max are same, if more than one entries then min and max are assigned correct values.
See below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class GradeAverage {

    private String filename;
    private List<String> invalidEntries;
    private List<Entry> validEntries;

    public GradeAverage() {
        invalidEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        validEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private static class Entry{
        private String name;
        private List<Integer> grades;
        public Entry() {
        grades = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void add(int g){
        grades.add(g);
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getAverage(){

        if(grades.size() == 0)
            return 0.0;

        double avg = 0.0;
        for(Integer x: grades){
            avg += x;
        }
        avg /= grades.size();
        return avg;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + getAverage() + "\n";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GradeAverage gradeApp = new GradeAverage();
    System.out.println("gradesheet.txt");
    gradeApp.setFilename("gradesheet.txt");

    gradeApp.readFile();
    gradeApp.process();

}

private void process() {
    Entry max = new Entry();
    Entry min = new Entry();

    //first loop, assign both min and max entry
    boolean firstTime = true; 

    for(Entry entry : validEntries){
        //first time only
        if(firstTime) {
            max = entry; 
            min = entry; 
            firstTime = false; 
        } else {
            //now search for minimum and maximum
             if(max.getAverage() < entry.getAverage())
                {
                    max = entry;
                }
                if(min.getAverage() >= entry.getAverage())
                {

                    //System.out.println("READ MIN " + min.toString());
                    min = entry;
                }
        }

    }
    System.out.print("MAX:\t"+max);
    System.out.print("MIN:\t"+min);
    System.out.println("\nExcluded Entries:");
    for(String str: invalidEntries){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

private void readFile() {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.exit(404);
    }
    while(in.hasNext()){
        String nextLine = in.nextLine();
        try{
            Entry entry = new Entry();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(nextLine);
            String name = tokenizer.nextToken();
            if(!valid(name))
               throw new Exception();
            entry.setName(name);
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                entry.add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
            }
            validEntries.add(entry);
              System.out.print("added\n"+entry.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            invalidEntries.add(nextLine);
        }
    }
    in.close();
}

private boolean valid(String name) {
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i){
        if(!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

}
```

I only modified the Process method, see below the usage of boolean flag and the if conditions:

```
private void process() {
    Entry max = new Entry();
    Entry min = new Entry();

    //first loop, assign both min and max entry
    boolean firstTime = true; 

    for(Entry entry : validEntries){
        //first time only
        if(firstTime) {
            max = entry; 
            min = entry; 
            firstTime = false; 
        } else {
            //now search for minimum and maximum
             if(max.getAverage() < entry.getAverage())
                {
                    max = entry;
                }
                if(min.getAverage() >= entry.getAverage())
                {

                    //System.out.println("READ MIN " + min.toString());
                    min = entry;
                }
        }

    }
    System.out.print("MAX:\t"+max);
    System.out.print("MIN:\t"+min);
    System.out.println("\nExcluded Entries:");
    for(String str: invalidEntries){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

After running it against the following input:

> I 30 12 43
>
> 64 46 love
>
> code 22 2 2 113
>
> somuch 13 99

I get the following output:

> MAX:  somuch 56.0
>
> MIN:  I 28.333333333333332
>
> Excluded Entries:
>
> 64 46 love

MAX was correct anyways, MIN is **I 30 12 43**